# meta_query with relation = AND not working as expected when combining EQUALS with NOT EQUALS

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I want to query my `player` post type for all those who do *not* have certain `colortoken` meta values (note that a `player` can have multiple `colortoken` meta_keys). I assumed I could do this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'player',
    'post_status'       => 'any',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,

    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'playerlevel',
            'value'   => 12,
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'colortoken',
            'value'     => 'blue',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
    ),
);

$playersQuery = get_posts($args);
```

This *should* return all players who are level 12 but **don't** have a blue `colortoken`. This works... but only if a `player` has a single `colortoken`. If I have a `player` post with two `colortoken` meta_values:

```
Post ID     => 158
playerlevel => 12
colortoken  => red
colortoken  => blue
```

...then this player (ID `158`) will be returned within the array, despite the fact that I asked for `colortoken != blue`. This seems to be an issue when there are multiple meta values with the same key, but the one you're trying to negate isn't the first one (so, if `blue` was the first value rather than the second, or it was the only `colortoken` meta value, then post `158` wouldn't be returned).

This only seems to be a problem when I combine `relation => AND` with a `compare => '='` & `compare => '!='`. If both of the compares are `=` (or removed, since it's implicit), then the returned array is as expected, even with multiple duplicate meta key/value pairs.

Am I missing something, or is this some kind of expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That player does have a colortoken which is not blue, because he has a red one. :)

SQL, and by extension the WP_Query system, is extremely literal. It's selecting a set of players who have a colortoken that is not blue and a level of 12. It's not excluding players with blue tokens, it's just selecting all of those that are not blue.

What you want here cannot be done in a WP_Query. While it is a good abstraction on top of SQL, it is not a perfect one and it cannot represent all possible queries that can be made. In particular, WP_Query is designed to select posts to include based on parameters. Here, you're wanting to exclude a set of posts based on that blue colortoken, and the meta_query doesn't have a way to do this.

Here's what your query looks like as you gave it, after WP_Query parses it (somewhat simplified):

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND 
( 
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'playerlevel' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '12' ) AND 
( mt1.meta_key = 'colortoken' AND mt1.meta_value != 'blue' ) 
) AND 
wp_posts.post_type = 'player' AND 
((wp_posts.post_status <> 'trash' AND wp_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

To actively exclude blue tokens, you need to use a subquery to exclude them. WP_Query can't do subqueries very well. Here's what will get you the posts you want to get:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND 
wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE 
meta_key = 'colortoken' AND meta_value = 'blue' 
) AND
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'playerlevel' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '12' ) AND 
wp_posts.post_type = 'player' AND 
((wp_posts.post_status <> 'trash' AND wp_posts.post_status <> 'auto-draft')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

That basically selects all level 12 players, except those with a blue token.

Comment: Thanks for the super-detailed answer! It's kind of what I expected, and I had an abstract idea that what you said in your first paragraph was the case. What I decided to do in the end was remove the `colortoken` query (so the request was just for `playerlevel= > 12`); then determine if the appropriate `colortoken` was missing in the subsequent loop. I'm never mad-keen on getting my hands dirty with raw SQL in WP if I don't need to!